# How to plot a stacked bar graph for 1d data(series) using plotly low level interface?

Tags: python, plotly, series, plotly-python, stacked-bar-chart

I am trying to replicate a stacked bar graph of a 1d data(series), something like this, [stacked bar graph using plotly high level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHOFU.png) using plotly low level interface. I have used high level interface to get the above output. Below is the code I used,

```py
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.bar(df_monthly_earnings.T, width =500,height= 500)
fig.show()
```

I want the exact output from a low level interface so, I tried this,

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure(
    data=[go.Bar(y=df_monthly_earnings.Earnings)]
)
fig.update_layout(width=500,height=500)
fig.show()
```

but the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R788P.png) is not as I expected. How to get the [desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHOFU.png) using low level interface? I want the earnings to be stacked just like the desired one. I have tried many different ways but nothing is working.

df_monthly_earnings contains,

```
+-------+---------------+
| Month |   Earnings    |
+-------+---------------+
|     1 |  4.488701e+07 |
|     2 |  3.707876e+07 |
|     3 |  6.888739e+07 |
|     4 |  7.085714e+07 |
|     5 |  7.376993e+07 |
|     6 |  8.048304e+07 |
|     7 |  1.170489e+08 |
|     8 |  2.191993e+08 |
|     9 |  7.833628e+07 |
|    10 |  1.359896e+08 |
|    11 |  1.081981e+08 |
|    12 |  1.070073e+08 |
+-------+---------------+
```

Comment: See the [example](https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/#stacked-bar-chart) of a stacked bar chart with a graph object.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimum reproducable example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @D.L sorry, now I have added all the code and the data that are relevant. Thank you!

Comment: @r-beginners I have tried those already, but I can't get the output as I expected. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical example of how easy it was to obtain a graph in Express, but it takes a lot of work to make it into a graph object. I need to get the data per pile and deal with it in a loop process in order to display the legend. Each pile also requires a color setting. Of the 24 standard colors available, 12 colors are used for color coding. I prepared 12 colors because the default colors would result in a repeat of 10 colors. The order of the legend is changed. I also added the title of the axis, etc.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

colors = px.colors.qualitative.Light24

fig = go.Figure()

for i,row in df_monthly_earnings.iterrows():
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=['Earnings'], y=[row['Earnings']], marker=dict(color=colors[i]), name=str(row['Month'].astype(int))))

fig.update_layout(width=500,
                  height=500, 
                  barmode='stack',
                  xaxis=dict(title_text='index'),
                  yaxis=dict(title_text='value'),
                  legend_title='Month',
                  legend_traceorder="normal",
                 )
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Glad I could be of service to you. Please refer to the following. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)